# no data received from $_FILES

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i'm using html5 dropzone for upload image with javascript

```
var dropZone = $('#dropZone'),
    maxFileSize = 1000000,
    img_id = 0;

// 
if (typeof (window.FileReader) == 'undefined') {
    dropZone.text('NO BROWSER SUPPORT!');
    dropZone.addClass('error');
}

// 
dropZone[0].ondragover = function () {
    dropZone.addClass('hover');
    return false;
};

// 
dropZone[0].ondragleave = function () {
    dropZone.removeClass('hover');
    return false;
};

// 
dropZone[0].ondrop = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    dropZone.removeClass('hover');
    dropZone.addClass('drop');

    var file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];

    // 
    if (file.size > maxFileSize) {
        dropZone.text('SO BIG FILE!');
        dropZone.addClass('error');
        return false;
    }

    // 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', uploadProgress, false);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
    xhr.open('POST', '/admin/admin.api.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-FILE-NAME', file.name);
    xhr.send(file);
};

// 
function uploadProgress(event) {
    var percent = parseInt(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
    dropZone.text('Загрузка: ' + percent + '%');
}

// 
function stateChange(event) {
    if (event.target.readyState == 4) {
        if (event.target.status == 200) {
            dropZone.text('SUCCESS!');
        } else {
            dropZone.text('FAIL!');
            dropZone.addClass('error');
        }
    }

}
```

Headers and data:

```
Request URL:http://***.com/admin/admin.api.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:uk-UA,uk;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:86016
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Host:***.com
Origin:http://***.com
Referer:http://***.com/admin/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.62 Safari/537.36
X-FILE-NAME:image.jpeg
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:132
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 29 Aug 2013 19:29:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze16
```

php script

```
    <?
    print_r($_POST);
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_FILES);
    ?>
```

returns

`Array()Array()Array()`

Comment: Any reason you're manually doing the XHR setup instead of using jQuery?

Comment: sending files over AJAX is possible, but only in recent browsers. For cross-browser support, you must use an old-style (synchronous) request (you can use `iframes` for it) or send the data as text and process it on the server.

Comment: @Dave OP is using HTML5 FileApi so I don't Think XHR2 will be a n issue.

Comment: @Musa ah yes. Fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$_FILES` array will only be populated if you send the file as multipart form data which you didn't, try using [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', uploadProgress, false);
xhr.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
xhr.open('POST', '/admin/admin.api.php');
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: just to note: this doesn't work on anything but the most recent IE (it works fine in all other browsers, obviously): http://caniuse.com/xhr2