# Post multipart/form-data using Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

For some reason I can not get the following script to work correctly, when submitting the form without using the script all works as it should, but when using the script to submit the form I only get the category and description in the post variables but no file. So my question is how do I get the script to post the file variable also.

Ajax

```
$("#img-post").click(function()
{
    $("#imgupload").submit(function(e)
    {
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax(
        {
            url : formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
            {
                $("#img").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">'+data+'</code></pre>');

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                alert('Error');
                document.getElementById('enquiry').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    });

    $("#imgupload").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="img" id="img"></div>

<form name="imgupload" id="imgupload" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="category" id="category" type="text" />
<input name="file" id="file" type="file" />
<textarea name="discription" id="discription" cols="68%" rows="8"></textarea><br>
<input type="button"  id="img-post" name="img-post" value="Add" />
</form>
```

Comment: can't be done. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: @andrew yes it can be done, that link is very old. see answer below.

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519771/no-data-received-from-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Data from file select elements is not serialized*

Taken from the docs page at:

https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

However, you can achieve this with the jquery ajax form plugin found here:

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

This plugin is nice because not only does it capture the form data (including files) you can easily send extra `$_POST` data in the `data` attribute of the ajax call along with your form.

Comment: Thank you, the plugin sounds promising I will look into it.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the plugin falls back to using an iframe when xhr2 is not available in older browsers https://github.com/malsup/form/

Comment: Thanks andrew, I was hoping to stay clear of iframes, but if it only falls back on older browsers that I can deal with :)